# Convert UTC timestamp to local timezone issue in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a Unix UTC timestamp to a local date format in Pandas. I've been looking through a few solutions but I can't quite get my head around how to do this properly.

I have a dataframe with multiple UTC timestamp columns which all need to be converted to a local timezone. Let's say EU/Berlin.

I first convert all the timestamp columns into valid datetime columns with the following adjustments:

`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')`
This works and gives me the following outcome e.g. *2019-01-18 15:58:25* if I know try to adjust the timezone for this Date Time I have tried both:

`df['date'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`
and
`df['date'].tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`

In both cases the error is: `TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex` and I don't understand why.

The problem must be that the DateTime column is not on the index. But even when I use `df.set_index('date')` and after I try the above options it doesn't work and I get the same error.

Also, if it would work it seems that this method only allows the indexed DateTime to be timezone adjusted. How would I then adjust for the other columns that need adjustment?

Looking to find some information on how to best approach these issues once and for all! Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should first specify that it is a datetime by adding the `.dt.` to a non index

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
```

This should be used if the column is not the index column.

Comment: It works! Was this too easy...? Why actually do you need to tell that it's UTC in ```tz_localize('UTC')``` when the datetime was converted from a UTC timestamp?

Comment: Pandas doesn't know what it is converting from-to. It sees a time, but it does not know that time is UTC, so it doesn't know how many hours ahead or behind the conversion time should be unless you tell it.